# WPF combobox inside Scrollviewer not working

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, telerik

I have a problem with the telerik Combobox which can be also reproduced for the basic WPF Combobox.

I have the following scenario : when the user tries to open the combobox, the entire page (including this control) should be shifted up, because in the bottom section the space will be occupied by a keyboard.

In order to do this I have catched the *GotFocus* event and I have updated the position of the Scrollviewer programmatically.

Here is the XAML :

```
  <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="2" x:Name="KeyBoardScrollViewer" PanningMode="VerticalOnly" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
 <telerik:RadComboBox Grid.Row="5" GotFocus="UIElement_OnGotFocus" LostFocus="UIElement_OnLostFocus"
                                 IsEditable="True"
                                 Grid.Column="1"
                                 ItemsSource="{Binding StreetOthers, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                 Text="{Binding SelectedStreetOthers, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                 Height="36" Width="250"
                                 HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                 VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                 FontSize="18" 
                                 Margin="10 0 0 0"
                                 Padding="5" />
 </ScrollViewer>
```

And the code behind :

```
  public double RememberedPoisitionOfScrollBar { get; set; }
   private void UIElement_OnGotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            Application.Current.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() =>
            {
                if (!Keyboard.IsOpen)
                {
                    Keyboard.IsOpen = true;
                    KeyBoardScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Visible;
                }
                Point relativePoint = ((FrameworkElement)sender).TransformToAncestor(KeyBoardScrollViewer)
                           .Transform(new Point(0, 0));


                KeyBoardScrollViewer.CanContentScroll = false;
                RememberedPoisitionOfScrollBar = relativePoint.Y - 5;
                var offset = KeyBoardScrollViewer.VerticalOffset + relativePoint.Y - 5; //sender.OccludedRect.Top
                KeyBoardScrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(offset);
                //KeyBoardScrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(offset);
                KeyBoardScrollViewer.UpdateLayout();
            });
            Keyboard.Width = this.ActualWidth;


        }

        private void UIElement_OnLostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

                Keyboard.IsOpen = false;
                KeyBoardScrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(KeyBoardScrollViewer.VerticalOffset - RememberedPoisitionOfScrollBar);
                KeyBoardScrollViewer.UpdateLayout();
                KeyBoardScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Hidden;

        }
```

This solution works, the combobox is moved to the top of the view, but I have a strange behavior. The combobox "content", remains in the original position, and is not updated according to the new position of the combobox . 
Here is the picture :
[image]

According to Telerik admins ([old post](http://www.telerik.com/forums/combobox-within-scrollviewer-scrolling-issue)) it is a WPF problem, but it has to be a workaround, no? Any idea is useful!

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the scroll viewer, subscribe to the ScrollChanged event:

```
ScrollChanged="KeyboardScrollView_OnScrollChanged"
```

and in the codebehind, if the dropdown is open when scroll occurs, close it and reopen it:

```
private void KeyboardScrollView_OnScrollChanged(object sender, ScrollChangedEventArgs e)
{
  if (TheComboBox.IsDropDownOpen)
  {
    TheComboBox.IsDropDownOpen = false;
    TheComboBox.IsDropDownOpen = true;
  }
}
```